# Как исправить ошибки при сборке ядра?

Tags: linux, unix, компиляция, kernel

```
make[2]: Выход из каталога `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
make EXTRAVERSION=-custom   ARCH=x86_64 prepare
make[2]: Вход в каталог `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
scripts/kconfig/conf -s arch/x86_64/Kconfig
make[2]: Выход из каталога `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
make[2]: Вход в каталог `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  UPD     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  UPD     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  SYMLINK include/asm -> include/asm-x86_64
  CC      arch/x86_64/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  GEN     include/asm-x86_64/asm-offsets.h
make[2]: Выход из каталога `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
echo done > debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf
make[1]: Выход из каталога `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
make -f debian/rules debian/stamp/conf/full-changelog
make[1]: Вход в каталог `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/full-changelog [new prereqs: ]======
for file in ChangeLog  Control  Control.bin86 config templates.in rules; do \
         cp -f  /usr/share/kernel-package/$file ./debian/;          \
    done
for dir  in Config docs examples ruleset scripts pkg po;    do      \
       cp -af /usr/share/kernel-package/$dir  ./debian/;            \
    done
install -p -m 755 /usr/share/kernel-package/rules debian/rules
sed         -e 's/=V/2.6.18-custom/g'  \
                -e 's/=D/2.6.18-custom-10.00.Custom/g'         -e 's/=A/amd64/g'  \
        -e 's/=SA//g'  \
        -e 's/=I//g'                    \
        -e 's/=CV/2.6/g'                \
        -e 's/=M/Unknown Kernel Package Maintainer <unknown@unconfigured.in.etc.kernel-pkg.conf>/g'             \
        -e 's/=ST/linux/g'      -e 's/=B/x86_64/g'    \
                  /usr/share/kernel-package/Control > debian/control
sed -e 's/=V/2.6.18-custom/g' -e 's/=D/2.6.18-custom-10.00.Custom/g'          \
        -e 's/=A/amd64/g' -e 's/=M/Unknown Kernel Package Maintainer <unknown@unconfigured.in.etc.kernel-pkg.conf>/g' \
        -e 's/=ST/linux/g'   -e 's/=B/x86_64/g'       \
        /usr/share/kernel-package/changelog > debian/changelog
chmod 0644 debian/control debian/changelog
make -f debian/rules debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf
make[2]: Вход в каталог `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
make[2]: `debian/stamp/conf/kernel-conf' не требует обновления.
make[2]: Выход из каталога `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
make[1]: Выход из каталога `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
echo done > debian/stamp/conf/minimal_debian
exec debian/rules  APPEND_TO_VERSION=-custom  INITRD=YES  kernel_image kernel_headers 
====== making target debian/stamp/conf/vars [new prereqs: ]======

====== making target debian/stamp/build/kernel [new prereqs: vars]======
This is kernel package version 12.036+nmu3.
restore_upstream_debianization
test ! -f scripts/package/builddeb.kpkg-dist || mv -f scripts/package/builddeb.kpkg-dist scripts/package/builddeb
test ! -f scripts/package/Makefile.kpkg-dist || mv -f scripts/package/Makefile.kpkg-dist scripts/package/Makefile
/usr/bin/make  EXTRAVERSION=-custom  ARCH=x86_64 \
                 bzImage
make[1]: Вход в каталог `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/linux/utsrelease.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/genksyms.o
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/lex.c
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.h
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/keywords.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/lex.o
scripts/genksyms/lex.c:1228:12: warning: ‘input’ defined but not used [-Wunused-function]
 static int input()
            ^
  SHIPPED scripts/genksyms/parse.c
  HOSTCC  scripts/genksyms/parse.o
  HOSTLD  scripts/genksyms/genksyms
  CC      scripts/mod/empty.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/mk_elfconfig
  MKELF   scripts/mod/elfconfig.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/file2alias.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/modpost.o
  HOSTCC  scripts/mod/sumversion.o
scripts/mod/sumversion.c: In function ‘get_src_version’:
scripts/mod/sumversion.c:384:16: error: ‘PATH_MAX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
  char filelist[PATH_MAX + 1];
                ^
scripts/mod/sumversion.c:384:16: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
scripts/mod/sumversion.c:384:7: warning: unused variable ‘filelist’ [-Wunused-variable]
  char filelist[PATH_MAX + 1];

make[3]: *** [scripts/mod/sumversion.o] Ошибка 1
    make[2]: *** [scripts/mod] Ошибка 2
    make[1]: *** [scripts] Ошибка 2
    make[1]: Выход из каталога `/usr/src/linux-2.6.18'
    make: *** [debian/stamp/build/kernel] Ошибка 2
```

Comment: Текст самих ошибок где?

Comment: @АнтонСазонов тут

Comment: Какова последовательность процесса сборки? Почему бы не взять более "отлаженную" версию?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> scripts/mod/sumversion.c:384:16: error: ‘PATH_MAX’ undeclared

древняя версия программы (2.6.18), [древние, давным-давно исправленные ошибки](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=17561).

---

наложите предлагаемый патч или вручную добавьте строку

```
#include <linux/limits.h>
```

в файл `scripts/mod/sumversion.c`.

---

патч, скопированный из сообщения об ошибке:

```
diff -r 557a4a0a5eac scripts/mod/sumversion.c
--- a/scripts/mod/sumversion.c  Fri May 30 19:08:50 2008 +0100
+++ b/scripts/mod/sumversion.c  Mon Jun 02 19:47:43 2008 +0900
@@ -8,6 +8,7 @@
 #include <errno.h>
 #include <string.h>
 #include "modpost.h"
+#include <linux/limits.h>

 /*
  * Stolen form Cryptographic API.
```

Comment: Вот за советы накладывать патчи вручную, пользоваться тарболами исходников и пр. поубивал бы. Есть же Git. Для кого он?!